# PHP array merge, remove [u]

Tags: php, array-merge

I have an array given below...

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [u] => Array
            (
                [id] => 396
                [first_name] => Gyan
                [last_name] => sharma
                [email] => gyan@gmail.com
                [phone_number] => 
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [u] => Array
            (
                [id] => 589
                [first_name] =>  deep
                [last_name] => sharma
                [email] => deep@gmail.com
                [phone_number] => 
            )

    )
)
```

I just want to remove the [u] from each array, Like array given below.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
         [id] => 396
         [first_name] => Gyan
         [last_name] => sharma
         [email] => gyan@gmail.com
         [phone_number] => 


    )

[1] => Array
    (
         [id] => 589
         [first_name] =>  deep
         [last_name] => sharma
         [email] => deep@gmail.com
         [phone_number] => 

    )
)
```

I can do this by `foreach()` loop, but it is lengthy process..

Can anyone tell me the shortest way for this.

Help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Lengthy? It's a single assignment.

Comment: Sir.... What if there is thousand of rows in array..

Comment: use `array_column()`

Comment: You *will* need to iterate over every entry. You *can't* get around that.

Comment: array_values($array,'u')

Comment: @JYoThI Warning (2): array_values() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given

Comment: @AlivetoDie your code is working... Thanks for help...
Thanks to all

Comment: @GyandeepSharma  glad to help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)  like below:-

```
$array = array_column($array,'u');
```

Output:- https://eval.in/833258

Answer (score 3):

Without foreach :

```
$new_array = array_map(function($element){
    return $element['u'];
},$old_array);

var_dump($new_array);
```

With foreach:

```
 $new_array = [];
    foreach($old_array as $value){
     $new_array[] = $value['u']
    }

    var_dump($new_array)
```

`$old_array` is your array and `$new_array` is array you want

Comment: @GyandeepSharma: Looks okay to me. What's wrong with it?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams  OP  specially mentioned:- `I can do this by foreach loop, but it is lengthy process..`  still answer is correct so +1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_map` and `array_shift` for this.

```
$a[0]['u']['name'] = "a";
$a[0]['u']['id'] = "a";

$a[1]['u']['name'] = "a";
$a[1]['u']['id'] = "a";



$a = array_map('array_shift', $a);
print_r($a,1);
```

Here is the [working example](https://eval.in/833257)

Comment: Clever, although this assumes that `u` is the only entry in the subarray.

Comment: Yes... It just shifts `u` index

Comment: It shifts the first index. In the question asked `u` is the only one, but readers need to understand the limitations of the code.